# What would be a faster method for handling pagination?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pagination

In the web application I am testing I have a list of elements that are displayed on a page. Depending on the number of elements in the list, the list becomes paginated.

The pagination is like this:

- If there is 1 page no pagination occurs.
- If there are 2 pages a next (>) button appear at the bottom of the page.
- If there are 3 or more pages, besides the next button(>) there will also be a last page button (>>).

I am currently using the following method to make sure that I always get to the last page of the list. I need this to then assert that the element I created is displayed since the element is always on the last page.
It works just fine but my problem is that when my tests reach this points, it takes about 20 seconds to run through this statement and since I use it on all tests it greatly slows down my testing process.
Is there a quicker method for the case I described?

```
public void jumpToLastPage(){ 
    List<WebElement> lastPage = driver.findElements(locator for last page button));
    if (lastPage.size() == 0){
        List<WebElement> nextPage = driver.findElements(locator for next page button));
        if(nextPage.size() >= 1){
            nextPage.get(0).click();
        }
    }
    else lastPage.get(0).click();
}
```

Comment: if you're using a framework it should have a pagination plugin that you can enable or look up online on how to integrate it.

Comment: Why do you need to go to the last page in all tests?

Comment: If the web performance is slow you will always have some network overhead clashes with browser extensions.

Comment: Your algorithm seems fine. Consider restructuring how you are calling this! For example: is it possible to navigate to the last page in a `@BeforeClass` method (assuming [tag:JUnit4]), and then run all your tests from that point?

Comment: I need to go to the last page to be able to assert that the element  created last in a previous test is displayed. And the elements last created are always last on the list. So if there are more pages for the list I needed a way to make sure that I am always on the last page when making the assert.

Comment: @SiKing - I can't do that since my tests are actually about creating an element, going to the last page and checking if it is there. Then deleting the element, going to the last page and checking if it is there. So this method is basically only used for the assertion of my tests.

Comment: Give us the URL of the webpage that you are trying to control, and we might be able to give you a method better than the one described above.

Comment: @Vlad Is that table sortable? If you'd sort it in reverse, your element would be on the first page.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts I discovered that the problem was actually from my setup in @BeforeMethod (TestNG).

My timeout was set to 10 seconds:
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

When it tries to find the element and fails it still lingers for 10 seconds in hopes of finding it and that is why it took me 20 seconds to go through the statement. I was on a single page and neither of the elements were shown.

I just added 2 lines of code to fix this:

```
public void jumpToLastPage(){
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    List<WebElement> lastPage = driver.findElements(By.xpath(locator));
    if (lastPage.size() == 0){
        List<WebElement> nextPage = driver.findElements(By.xpath(locator));
        if(nextPage.size() >= 1){
            nextPage.get(0).click();
        }
    }
    else lastPage.get(0).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

This way, it sets the implicit time to wait to 3 seconds while it does the statement and then goes back to the default 10 seconds once it is done greatly decreasing the time it takes to go through the statement.

Thank you all for your answers nonetheless.

Answer (score -1):

I think this would be faster:

```
public void jumpToLastPage(){
    List<WebElement> lastPageButton = driver.findElements(By locator);
    List<WebElement> nextPageButton = driver.findElements(By locator);

    // if last page button is on the page, click it
    if(lastPageButton.size() != 0) {
        lastPageButton.get(0).click();
    }
    // else if next page button, click it
    else if(nextPageButton.size() != 0) {
        nextPageButton.get(0).click();
    }
    // otherwise you should be on the only page
}
```

Comment: This method takes exactly the same time as the one I have now. But thank you nonetheless :). Still looking for an answer though.